# error sending multiple mails through smtp

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to develop a small python application that allows it's user to send multiple mails through python, I am using gmail, I have allowed Access for less secure apps, it doesn't send.
I have searched stackoverflow for similar problems, but it seemed that most of the used codes are completely different in implementation, even after trying many of hem, they all through exception

```
import smtplib 
from telnetlib import Telnet

def addSenders(message):
    num = input("enter number of recievers : ")
    num = int (num)
    i = 0
    emailList = []
    while i < num :
        nameStr = input("enter name")
        mailStr = input("enter e-mail")
        emailList.append(mailStr)
        if i == 0:
            message += nameStr + " <" + mailStr + ">"
            print(message)
        else:
            message += "," + nameStr + " <" + mailStr + ">"
        i = i + 1
    return emailList, message


sender = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
password = "xxxx"


message = """From: xxxx xxxx <xxxxx@gmail.com>
To: To """
to, message = addSenders(message)

message += """
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: Any Subject!

<h1> Good Morning :D <h1>
"""


server =  smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()

server.login(sender, password)
try:
   server.sendmail(sender, [to], message)         
   print ("Successfully sent email")
except:
   print ("Error: unable to send email")
server.quit()
```

output : `Error: unable to send email`

Comment: I think it is more informative not to catch the exception (during debug), then we will be able to see what kind of exception was thrown by `server.sendmail`. Could you remove try-except statement, re-run your code and provide traceback?

Comment: why don't you catch the exception  by except Exception as e: newline print str(e)

Comment: i removed the try-catch, and that was the exception : unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: The `[to]` bit seems odd: you are wrapping the list of receivers (`to`, as returned by `addSenders`) in another list. Can you paste the full traceback?

Comment: i tried to add some elements to a list, then printed both the new one and [to], they both are the same

Comment: problem was solved, i just removed the [] from "to", i was inserting a list into other list